# Mixed Integer programming, the big M

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, indicator-constraints, big-m

[image]

In the constraints below, why have they used the big M? What do we look for in order to identify the big M in other questions?

Comment: big M constraints are used to model constraints with implications (e.g. $y=0 \implies x=0$) so you can start by identifying where you have implications in your model.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common modeling techniques in operations research.

Another interpretation is **if-then relationship** or **indicator**. When you have to count how many days you have to setup to produce then you can introduce this big-M formulation.

In this case, you can imagine that the big-M value is your **maximum production capacity**, since you never hope the value of $x$ would exceed your production capacity.

Of course this big-M value should be always valid for your entire problem, otherwise you would obtain wrong counting number on setup variables.